# Installing php support to Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have apache2 up and running and it does work, I use the server for other services. I want to run a service that requires php support for apache2. I followed the installation instructions  and installed the various packages that were asked for and I get the following error:

```
sudo a2enmod php
ERROR: Module php does not exist!
```

Here is a list of the installed packages I have installed that are related to php:

```
libapache2-mod-php/bionic,now 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all [installed]
libapache2-mod-php7.2/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php/bionic,now 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 all [installed]
php-common/bionic,now 1:60ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
php7.2/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 all [installed,automatic]
php7.2-cli/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-common/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-json/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-opcache/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-readline/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Is there something that I'm missing? I've done this before for earlier versions of Ubuntu Server and I do seem to remember that every time it is a large hassle.

Please let me know if more information is required and thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to use `mod_php`, which is considered fairly antiquated (it is very resource hungry) rather than the more modern `php-fpm`.

If you're happy to continue this way, then you're probably not using the name of the mod correctly. You can list the mods you have available with:

`ls /etc/apache2/mods-available`

I suspect you'll find, among the list of mods, that the one you want i `php7.2`, rather than `php`. In this case you need the command to be:

`sudo a2enmod php7.2`

The better, more modern, faster and more frugal way to install `php` is using `php-fpm`. It is often the [recommended way to run PHP in Apache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP).

```
sudo apt remove libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt install php-fpm
```

Then:

`a2enmod proxy_fcgi`

You can see more at Jim Salter's excellent blog [here](https://jrs-s.net/2019/05/25/installing-wordpress-on-apache-the-modern-way/).

Comment: Thanks very much for help. I've mucked about with the php installation and found that the classic "phpinfo" web page worked just fine which to me seem to mean that php installation was working just fine. Am I wrong? I did some more digging and when the application that I was trying to install had instructions that did not agree with the general setup of any kind of a web app installation for apache2 I just ripped it all out and decide to move on.

Comment: I had the same issue and couldn't use any of those! I'm gonna jump to xampp/lampp.